# Rank in hive from count(column) from table

Tags: sql, hive, rank

If I want to select `count(user_name), country` from the table in hive. What command should I use to get the result as top 2 country for the most user_name?

How can I use rank function?

```
id | user_name | country
 1 | a         | UK
 2 | b         | US
 3 | c         | AUS
 4 | d         | ITA
 5 | e         | UK
 6 | f         | US
```

the result should be:

```
rank| num_user_name | country
 1  | 2             | US
 1  | 2             | UK
 2  | 1             | ITA
 2  | 1             | AUS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `dense_rank` analytic function:

```
with cte as (
    select   country, 
             count(user_name) as num_user_name
    from     tbl
    group by country
), cte2 as (
    select   dense_rank() over (order by num_user_name desc) as ranked,
             num_user_name,
             country
    from     cte
)
select   ranked,
         num_user_name,
         country
from     cte2
where    ranked <= 2
order by 1
```

Comment: Can I limit the rank by this command? I've tried with where ranked <= 2 but it didn't work.

Comment: You can just make the final query a CTE and the select from that with a `where ranked <= 2`. See updated answer. And a fix to it ;)

Comment: you forgot to give 'cte2' in the last query command, but thank you!!

Comment: See end of my comment above ;-) But good that you arrived at that!

Answer (score 1):

A subquery is not necessary:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by count(*)) as rank,
       country, 
       count(*) as num_user_name
from t
group by country
order by count(*) desc, country;
```